# search variable and corresponding value in bash

Tags: bash

I have below sample file:

```
Jul 16 00:01:24  abc postfix/smtp[28719]: 51AEqwqwq06: to=<simon.naish@xyz.com>, relay=none, delay=0.17, delays=0.17/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026: Connection refused)
Jul 16 00:01:36  abc postfix/smtp[28655]: E444qw002: to=<r-ff001101082d5bf235740884e558eea95@comms.frong.com>, relay=in.emailct.com[63.20.111.76]:25, delay=39, delays=0.06/0/0.92/38, dsn=2.1.5, status=deliverable (250 2.1.5 r-ff001101082d5bf2355ff8740884e558eea95@comms.thrwwsixtyabc.com )
Jul 16 00:01:43  abc postfix/smtp[28815]: F19Dwq003: to=<sullcrom@em1.SulivanCromwell.com>, relay=em1.SullivanCromwell.com[223.222.222.2]:25, delay=162708, delays=162705/0.3/1.6/0.62, dsn=4.2.2, status=deferred (host em1.SullivanCromwell.com[223.222.222.2] said: 452 4.2.2 Mailbox full (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

I want to display highest integer value of "delay=" and corresponding line from file.

sample output:

```
longest delay was: **162708** on and at **Jul 16 00:01:43** on server **abc**0

Jul 16 00:01:43  postfix/smtp[28815]: F19Dwq003: to=<sullcrom@emm.SullivanAndCromwell.com>, relay=emm.SullivanCromwell.com[205.22.33.33]:25, delay=162708, delays=162705/0.3/1.6/0.62, dsn=4.2.2, status=deferred (host emm.SullivanCromwell.com[223.222.222.2] said: 452 4.2.2 Mailbox full (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All together:

```
$ data=$(grep -nPo '(?<=delay=)\d+' file | sort -rn -t: -k2 | head -1)
$ line=${data%%:*}
$ delay=${data##*:}
$ awk -v line=$line -v delay=$delay 'NR==line {print "longest delay was **", delay, "** on", $1, $2, "at", $3, "at server",$4, "\n\n",$0}' file
longest delay was ** 162708 ** on Jul 16 at 00:01:43 at server abc 

 Jul 16 00:01:43  abc postfix/smtp[28815]: F19Dwq003: to=<sullcrom@em1.SulivanCromwell.com>, relay=em1.SullivanCromwell.com[223.222.222.2]:25, delay=162708, delays=162705/0.3/1.6/0.62, dsn=4.2.2, status=deferred (host em1.SullivanCromwell.com[223.222.222.2] said: 452 4.2.2 Mailbox full (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

#### Explanation (spoiler: it can be boring)

You can firstly get the following:

```
$ grep -nPo '(?<=delay=)\d+' file | sort -rn -t: -k2
3:162708
2:39
1:0
```

Let's split it in parts:

```
$ grep -nPo '(?<=delay=)\d+' file
1:0
2:39
3:162708
```

gives the number of line and the value of `delay=`. As we just want the first line, we do `head -1`. Then we sort it by number with `sort -rn -t: -k2`. First row will be `line number:delay`.

So we have the following to get the `delay` and `line`:

```
$ grep -nPo '(?<=delay=)\d+' file | sort -rn -t: -k2 | head -1
3:162708
```

And

```
$ line=${data%%:*}  # returns value after :
$ delay=${data##*:} # returns value before :
```

Then it is time for `awk`:

```
awk -v line=$line -v delay=$delay 'NR==line {print "longest delay was **", delay, "** on", $1, $2, "at", $3, "at server",$4}' file
```

- `awk -v var=$some_var` gives to awk the value of a session var to be used inside the command.
- `NR==line {}` makes the actions to be performed just when it is in the line `line` of the file.
- `{print "longest delay was **", delay, "** on", $1, $2, "at", $3, "at server",$4, "\n\n",$0}` prints the data the way it is asked in the question. `$1`, `$2`...  correspond to the field position in the line. `$0` corresponds to the full line.